# Find a basis of the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have the vector space $V$ of polynomialsof one variable with real coefficients of degree $\leq 3$. We consider the operator $L:V\to V$,  $L(p(x))=3p(x)-xp'(x)$.

I want to ta calculate a basis of the kernel.

I have done the following:

Let $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Then $p'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$.

So we have $$L(p(x))=3p(x)-xp'(x)=bx^2+2cx+3d$$

We have that $$L(p(x))=0\Rightarrow bx^2+2cx+3d=0 \Rightarrow b=c=d=0$$ That means that $$p(x)\in \ker (L)\iff p(x)=ax^3 \ , \ a\in \mathbb{R}$$ or not? So $$\ker(L)=\{ax^3\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ For a basis do we take the coefficients? I mean $(a,b,c,d)=(1,0,0,0)$ ? Or is the basis $\{x^3\}$ ?

Comment: The basis is just $\left\lbrace x^3 \right\rbrace$.

Comment: We have that a basis of $V$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ and a basis of $\ker (L)$ is $\{x^3\}$, is then a basis of the quotient space $V/\ker (L)$ the set $\{1,x,x^2\}$ ? @AniruddhaDeshmukh

Comment: Since the quotient space is defined to be $V / \ker \left( L \right) = \left\lbrace v + \ker \left( L \right) | v \in V \right\rbrace$, then the basis should be $\left\lbrace 1 + x^3, x + x^3, x^2 + x^3 \right\rbrace$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: not quite, the basis elements of the quotient are as you say sets, so they are [not what you say] $\{1+ax^3\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $\{x+ax^3\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $\{x^2+ax^3\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Doyou mean that the basis of $V/\ker (L)$ is a set of these sets? @ancientmathematician

Comment: The basis is a set of three elements, namely the three sets I wrote down.

Comment: So you mean that the basis is $\{\{1+ax^3\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}, \{x+ax^3\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}, \{x^2+ax^3\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}\}$, right? @ancientmathematician

Comment: That's what I said, yes.